# Why R's ifelse statements Return Error in write.csv()?

Tags: r, csv, if-statement

I want to save CSV file with ifelse function

```
my_data<-data.frame(fruits = c("orange","banana"),prices=c(2,3))

ifelse(5>3,write.csv(my_data,"mydata.csv",row.names = F),1+1)
```

I am getting this error in R console:

```
Error in ans[test & ok] <- rep(yes, length.out = length(ans))[test & ok] :
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: I think the problem is, that the ifelse function assumes that you return something, but write.csv does not. You could use a normal if() else and it would work just fine.

Comment: ok, I understand why ifelse not working on write.csv thx

Answer (score 2):

Linus  has explained the reason why `ifelse` is not working. But if you still want to use `ifelse` to write to `csv` file then `write_csv` from `readr` package can be your option.

```
library(readr)
my_data<-data.frame(fruits = c("orange","banana"),prices=c(2,3))    
ifelse(5>3,write_csv(my_data,"mydata.csv"),1+1)
```